# Symfony3 file uploader

Tags: php, file, symfony, uploader

Welcome, 
I'm a little newbie in symfony but I wanna create website with upload file. I found good bundle https://github.com/SymfonyContrib/FileFieldBundle but when I try add it by composer then it's not possible becouse lastest correct Symfony version is 2.3. Anyone know how import it to Symfony3?

Or anyone have some bundle with file uploader based on jQuery File Upload working with Symfony3?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that bundle unless the maintainer of the bundle migrates it to Symfony 3. In his [composer.json](https://github.com/SymfonyContrib/FileFieldBundle/blob/master/composer.json) the required symfony version is stated as `~2.3` which is equivalent to `>=2.3 <3.0.0` ([composer version syntax](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#tilde)). You are of course free to fork the bundle on github and make the required changes yourself to make it compatible with Symfony 3 and issue a pull request.